# close votes vs votes remaining

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

I am new to the review part of Stack Overflow and I am trying to understand what is the meaning of *votes remaining* in the **Review | Close Vote**.

For example: Today I was at my 39 vote and it said that there was still 21 votes remaining.

> [image]

However, after my 40 vote:

> [image]

So, apparently I have started with 60 votes but I can use only 40?

Comment: Review is separate process where you are limited to specific amount of review actions. You can still cast close votes outside the scope of review if you have votes remaining. Review action might be upvote, downvote, vote to close, vote to delete, approve suggested edit, reject suggested edit and maybe more. Each of those actions can also be done outside the review.

Comment: As a side note: backtick is for **inline code** please don't abuse it. To highlight key words we have bold or italics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of the review queues have their separate daily limits relevant to the number of items in the queue (as close votes stand, that's currently 40). That's not to say that you can't close anything else you see, you still have more votes for that.

However, that is confusing. I think it would be nice if when you were in review mode that dialog said **x votes remaining (x in review queue)** or something similar to further disambiguate things.

Like this:

[image: review queue]

Comment: The limit depends on the queuesize: large queue 40 reviews, small queue 20 reviews.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe Updated, didn't realise that! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

*votes remaining* is *close* votes remaining not *daily review limit* remaining. You may close any question directly from the question page even after your daily review limit is over.

- **Close votes remaining**: How many close votes can you cast per day.
- **Daily review limit**: How many posts can you review per day.