# How many close votes do I actually have each day?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

The close votes count has been bothering me for a while now. I want to make sure I fully understand how the system works and maybe update the FAQ so it's less confusing for people.

The [SO Help-centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) says we have 50 close votes each day.

I am 6K+ on SO.

I have used 40 votes in the Close Votes queue today but If I go into any question and click on close, it says that I have 12 votes left ( after using 8 close votes directly from question pages earlier today - not the queue )

Does that mean I actually have 60 votes? I am confused.

Is there anywhere to find the rep lvl vs. the amount of close votes allowed per question and review queue?

Something like

1K+ = 20 votes on questions
2K+ = 30 votes on questions
3K+ = 35 votes on questions / 40 in the review queue
4K+ = 40 votes on questions / 50 in the review queue

Comment: Somewhat related: [close votes vs votes remaining](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172805/close-votes-vs-votes-remaining)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), you have 24 close votes to use per day, but 50 if you're on Stack Overflow.

There is an entirely separate limit of 40 reviews that can be done in the close vote review queue.  Note that this is not *close votes* it is simply reviews.  Reviewing an audit is a review, but it uses no votes; voting to keep a question open is a review, but it uses no votes.  Closing a question that is later deleted is a review, but gives you back your vote.

The number of votes isn't affected by your current rep, so long as you have the 3k needed to vote to close in the first place.